# How to merge two data frames by first 4 digits of mergeable values only

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge

I have two data frames with **Latitude** , **Longitude** and **speed** values. **DF1** has three values after the decimal point and DF2 has five values after the decimal point respectively. **I want to merge DF1 and DF2 by Latitude and Longitude but by first 4 values.** If the first four values of Lat and Long are matching then merge the rest of column in resultant DF. But ***I also want to keep the values after three decimal point that are existing in DF2***. If the Lat and Long are not matching their first four values then ill ignore it. Below is the example for more clarification.

Thanks

DF1

| A_Lat | A_Long | A_Speed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5.667 | 2.443 | 1345 |

```
DF1 <- structure(list(A_Lat = c(5.667, 5.667, 5.667, 5.667, 5.663, 5.662
), A_Long = c(2.443, 2.445, 2.445, 2.445, 2.445, 2.445), A_Speed = c(1345L, 
3551L, 3551L, 3551L, 3551L, 3551L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
6L))
```

DF2

| B_Lat | B_Long | B_Speed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5.66781 | 2.44323 | 2345 |

```
DF2 <- structure(list(B_Lat = c(5.66781, 5.66783, 5.66743, 5.66723, 
5.66734, 5.66712), B_Long = c(2.44323, 2.44534, 2.44523, 2.44512, 
2.44512, 2.44543), B_Speed = c(2345L, 4551L, 5551L, 7551L, 7551L, 
8551L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 6L))
```

Resultant DF

| R_Lat | R_Long | R_B_Speed | R_A_Speed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5.66781 | 2.44323 | 2345 | 1345 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- one approach would be to use the first four significant digits (`signif`) and {dplyr} for convenience:

```
library(dplyr)

DF1 |> 
    left_join(DF2 |>
              mutate(across(contains(c('Lat', 'Long')),
                            ~ signif(.x, 4),
                            .names = '{.col}_Short')
                     ),
              by = c(A_Lat = 'B_Lat_Short')
              ) |>
    select(-ends_with('_Short'))
```

```
   A_Lat A_Long A_Speed   B_Lat  B_Long B_Speed
1  5.667  2.443    1345 5.66743 2.44523    5551
2  5.667  2.443    1345 5.66723 2.44512    7551
3  5.667  2.443    1345 5.66734 2.44512    7551
4  5.667  2.443    1345 5.66712 2.44543    8551
## ...
```

- working with spatial data, you could also use a spatial join (by proximity within an allowable distance), e. g. with {sf}.

```
library(sf)

## convert DF1 and DF2 to spatial dataframes in one go (using `Map`)
spatial_DFs <- 
    c('DF1', 'DF2') |>
    Map(f = \(df_name){
        get(df_name) |>
            rowwise() |>
            mutate(geometry = (\(...) st_sfc(st_point(unlist(...))))
                                  (c_across(contains(c('_Lat', '_Long'))))
            ) |>
            st_sf(crs = 4326) |> ## set WGS84 (EPSG 4326) as coord. system
            ## add some snapping tolerance by growing points
            ## into circles of 100 m radius:
            st_buffer(100)
    })

## inspect buffered points:
spatial_DFs |>
    Reduce(f = bind_rows) |>
    ggplot() + geom_sf(aes(fill = is.na(A_Lat)), alpha = .2)
```

[image: preview of buffered points]

```
## join spatially:
with(spatial_DFs,
     st_join(DF1, DF2)
     )
```

```
Simple feature collection with 18 features and 6 fields
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 5.661099 ymin: 2.442099 xmax: 5.667909 ymax: 2.445907
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
# A tibble: 18 x 7
   A_Lat A_Long A_Speed                            geometry B_Lat B_Long B_Speed
 * <dbl>  <dbl>   <int>                       <POLYGON [°]> <dbl>  <dbl>   <int>
 1  5.67   2.44    1345 ((5.666492 2.442246, 5.666502 2.44~  5.67   2.44    2345
 2  5.67   2.44    3551 ((5.666142 2.444698, 5.66615 2.444~  5.67   2.45    4551
 3  5.67   2.44    3551 ((5.666142 2.444698, 5.66615 2.444~  5.67   2.45    5551
 4  5.67   2.44    3551 ((5.666142 2.444698, 5.66615 2.444~  5.67   2.45    7551
## ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set up key columns for lat / long in each data frame by multiplying by 1000 and rounding. Next add an index column in `DF1` using its row numbers. You can then do a left join on the lat / long key columns and filter out the unique indices from DF1. Finally drop the unused columns and rename the resulting columns as you see fit:

```r
library(tidyverse)

DF2 %>%
  mutate(key_lat = as.integer(B_Lat * 1000),
         key_long = as.integer(B_Long * 1000)) %>%
  left_join(DF1 %>%
               mutate(key_lat = as.integer(A_Lat * 1000),
                      key_long = as.integer(A_Long * 1000),
                      rownum = row_number()),
            by = c("key_lat", "key_long")) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(rownum)) %>%
  select(B_Lat, B_Long, B_Speed, A_Speed) %>%
  rename(R_Lat = B_Lat, R_Long = B_Long, 
         R_B_Speed = B_Speed, R_A_Speed = A_Speed)

#>     R_Lat  R_Long R_B_Speed R_A_Speed
#> 1 5.66781 2.44323      2345      1345
#> 2 5.66783 2.44534      4551      3551
#> 3 5.66783 2.44534      4551      3551
#> 4 5.66783 2.44534      4551      3551
```